# How to select Excel Add-ins with a script?

Tags: excel, powershell, comobject

I'm trying to get a solution to select specific Excel Add-ins with a script.

I was able to catch all the information about Excel.Application and change "Installed" property to $true, but it comes back to $false when the code stops running. Anybody knows a different solution or a way to save the Excel property?

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$excel.Addins | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq "NameOfAdd-ins" } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Installed = $true
}
```

$_.Installed property should stay $true after Run-Time

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing. I changed the 'Solver Add-in' to `Installed=$true` using the method you show, and then did `$excel.quit()`, and when I checked in Excel by launching it manually it showed as active, and when I created a new Excel com object in PS it still showed as installed. Same when I set it to `$false`

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. Appreciate